# Cannot read property 'api' of undefined in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.content === "channelCreate" ) {
    guild.channels.create('test channel', { type: "text" })
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error)
  }
}
```

When I run this code, I am getting this error message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'api' of undefined" and I honestly don't have any idea what the problem is.
Please help :(
I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your error. In the third line you wrote

```js
    guild.channels.create('test channel', { type: "text" })
```

But guild is underfined so it creates a problem in discord.js library.

Use

```js
    message.guild.channels.create('test channel', { type: "text" })
```

Hope i helped

Answer (score 1):

You most likely used Enmap. You most likely do not want to do this and instead use the regular Discord collection. You also do not have any word "api" in that code -- a stack trace would be helpful.